# Kotlin Objective-C interop usage of Protocol initialization in Kotlin interface

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native, kotlin-interop

I just tried to use my compiled staticLibrary using objective-c code.

here's what inside my nativeLib.a :

NativeHello.h

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@protocol NativeDelegate
- (void) test: (NSString *)strData;
@end

@interface NativeHello: NSObject
{
     id<NativeDelegate> nativeDelegate;
}
- (NativeSocket*) init;
- (NSString*) getVersion;
- (void) setDelegate: (id) newDelegate;

@end
```

NativeHello.m

```objectivec
#import "NativeHello.h"

- (NativeSocket*) init {
      self = [super init];
      return self;
}
- (NSString*) getVersion {
      if(nativeDelegate != nil) [nativeDelegate test:@"0.0.2"];
      return @"0.0.1";
}
- (void) setDelegate: (id) newDelegate {
     nativeDelegate = newDelegate;
}
```

Then I included this static lib to my multiplatform project using native interop with `.def` file.
in short after I interop the staticLibrary, the `.klib` file generated and as expected the `@protocol` translated to `interface`

then I want to implement the interface because I want to get the callback result from the interface function call, so I created something like this:

```kotlin
actual object PlatformSpecific : NativeDelegateProtocol {

       actual fun getVersion() : String {
              val nativeHello = NativeHello()
              nativeHello.setDelegate(this)
              return nativeHello.getVersion()
       }

       override fun test(strData : String) {
            println("test : $strData")
       }
}
```

Then I create simple unit test to test the `getVersion()` function  and I got this error :

`Kotlin implementation of Objective-C protocol must have Objective-C superclass (e.g. NSObject)`

so I changed my code to this :

```kotlin
actual object PlatformSpecific : NSObject(), NativeDelegateProtocol {

       actual fun getVersion() : String {
              val nativeHello = NativeHello()
              nativeHello.setDelegate(this)
              return nativeHello.getVersion()
       }

       override fun test(strData : String) {
            println("test : $strData")
       }
}
```

then I try to run my test again and get a different error message :

```
e: Compilation failed: Assertion failed
 * Source files: 
 * Compiler version info: Konan: 1.4.30 / Kotlin: 1.4.30
 * Output kind: PROGRAM
e: java.lang.AssertionError: Assertion failed
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGenerator.typeInfoForAllocation(CodeGenerator.kt:69)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.FunctionGenerationContext.getObjectValue(CodeGenerator.kt:1090)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.evaluateGetObjectValue(IrToBitcode.kt:921)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.evaluateExpression(IrToBitcode.kt:896)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.evaluateSetField(IrToBitcode.kt:1629)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.evaluateExpression(IrToBitcode.kt:883)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.evaluateContainerExpression(IrToBitcode.kt:1863)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.evaluateExpression(IrToBitcode.kt:890)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.generateStatement(IrToBitcode.kt:910)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitFunction(IrToBitcode.kt:749)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitConstructor(IrToBitcode.kt:575)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitConstructor(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitConstructor(IrToBitcode.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitConstructor(IrToBitcode.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrConstructor.accept(IrConstructor.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:271)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitClass(IrToBitcode.kt:791)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitClass(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitClass(IrToBitcode.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitClass(IrToBitcode.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.acceptChildren(IrFileImpl.kt:66)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor$visitFile$$inlined$using$lambda$1.invoke(IrToBitcode.kt:518)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor$visitFile$$inlined$using$lambda$1.invoke(IrToBitcode.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.runAndProcessInitializers(IrToBitcode.kt:331)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitFile(IrToBitcode.kt:517)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitFile(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:38)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitFile(IrToBitcode.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitFile(IrToBitcode.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.accept(IrFileImpl.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.serialization.KonanIrModuleFragmentImpl.acceptChildren(KonanIrlinker.kt:253)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptChildrenVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:275)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitModuleFragment(IrToBitcode.kt:355)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoid$DefaultImpls.visitModuleFragment(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitModuleFragment(IrToBitcode.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.CodeGeneratorVisitor.visitModuleFragment(IrToBitcode.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.serialization.KonanIrModuleFragmentImpl.accept(KonanIrlinker.kt:250)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementVisitorVoidKt.acceptVoid(IrElementVisitorVoid.kt:271)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.BitcodePhasesKt$codegenPhase$1.invoke(BitcodePhases.kt:269)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.llvm.BitcodePhasesKt$codegenPhase$1.invoke(BitcodePhases.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanLoweringPhasesKt$makeKonanModuleOpPhase$1.invoke(KonanLoweringPhases.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanLoweringPhasesKt$makeKonanModuleOpPhase$1.invoke(KonanLoweringPhases.kt:60)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:30)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:30)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:23)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:30)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.NamedCompilerPhase.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.KonanDriverKt.runTopLevelPhases(KonanDriver.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native.doExecute(K2Native.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:227)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion$mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer$1.invoke(K2Native.kt:270)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.UtilKt.profileIf(Util.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.UtilKt.profile(Util.kt:21)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2Native$Companion.mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer(K2Native.kt:285)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.bc.K2NativeKt.mainNoExitWithGradleRenderer(K2Native.kt:485)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt$daemonMain$1.invoke(main.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt$daemonMain$1.invoke(main.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.mainImpl(main.kt:17)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.utilities.MainKt.daemonMain(main.kt:43)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor422.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KotlinToolRunner.runInProcess(KotlinToolRunner.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KotlinToolRunner.run(KotlinToolRunner.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinNativeCompile.compile(KotlinNativeTasks.kt:334)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinNativeLink.compile(KotlinNativeTasks.kt:657)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:570)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:555)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:538)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:279)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:268)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:159)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I've trying to googling this issue and I'm still not found the solution (or maybe just not found the right keyword). What I did wrong in this implementation ? Is there any solution since I need some kind of this callback interface to received any loop result (e.g native client socket).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug.

Thank you for reporting it to the Kotlin issue tracker. If anyone else encountered this bug, please let us know here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45511. As soon as the ticket is resolved, I'll post an update on this answer.

EDIT: this is a comment from the ticket.

> Adding Objective-C super types to a Kotlin `object` declaration is not supported at the moment.
> The compiler should, of course, clearly indicate that instead of crashing.
>
> As a workaround, please declare `PlatformSpecific` as class.